# Linear model when both dependent and independent variables have unpaired replicates

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, biostatistics

I've got a set of experiments where 3 replicate measurements are done for rat cell lines and for human cell lines under different conditions using various compounds. I am trying to predict the response in human based on the response in rat. Assuming the replicates are not paired (replicate 1 in rat doesn't correspond to replicate 1 in human), is this the correct way to model this?

```
    rat <- matrix(rnorm(15),5)
    human <- matrix(rnorm(15),5)
    compound <- c("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5")
    
    y <- NULL
    x <- NULL
    c <- NULL
    for (i in 1:5) {
        y <- c(y, human[i,1])
        x <- c(x, rat[i,1])
        c <- c(c, compound[i])
        y <- c(y, human[i,1])
        x <- c(x, rat[i,2])
        c <- c(c, compound[i])
        y <- c(y, human[i,1])
        x <- c(x, rat[i,3])
        c <- c(c, compound[i])
        y <- c(y, human[i,2])
        x <- c(x, rat[i,1])
        c <- c(c, compound[i])
        y <- c(y, human[i,2])
        x <- c(x, rat[i,2])
        c <- c(c, compound[i])
        y <- c(y, human[i,2])
        x <- c(x, rat[i,3])
        c <- c(c, compound[i])
        y <- c(y, human[i,3])
        x <- c(x, rat[i,1])
        c <- c(c, compound[i])
        y <- c(y, human[i,3])
        x <- c(x, rat[i,2])
        c <- c(c, compound[i])
        y <- c(y, human[i,3])
        x <- c(x, rat[i,3])
        c <- c(c, compound[i])
    }

    lme(y ~ x, random = ~1|c)
```

So I'm basically considering all combinations between the 3 replicates since they are not paired.

Comment: An `R` comment:  `y <- rep(as.vector(t(human)), each=3); c<- rep(compound, each=9); x ...` would give you the same stuff much faster and with less visual clutter. Additionally: you seem to discard information about the fact you have replicates. You sure you want to do that?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try something like `lme(y ~ x, random = ~1|c, rat_subject, human_subject)`

Comment: Another R comment: please don't name a variable `c`, because that is also the command *concatenate* (which you also use in the code).

Comment: Your scientific idea/question isn't totally clear to me. Is it that the mean response (to some set of compounds) in humans should be positively correlated with the mean response in rats?